# Decrement a value from an existing array if a condition has met using a method - OOP

Tags: java, arrays, methods, equals

I am trying to create a method for a LIBRARY exercise, however, I have some issues with the method
RentBook().
Basically, I use to a method to add a book that I want to rent, when using my code it decrements -1 all stocks instead of the one is chosen.

code:

```
public String rentBook(Book book) {
    for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
        if ((books[i].equals(book)))
            inStock[i]--;
        }
        return "book name" + book;
    }
}
```

my equals function:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Book other = (Book) obj;
    if (id != other.id)
        return false;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        return false;
    if (Double.doubleToLongBits(price) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.price))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

what I get:

[11, 39, 43, 1, 12, 3]

What I want:

[12, 39, 44, 2, 13, 4]

Comment: Can you show the equals function of Book class? It looks like the equals functions is returning true for all the books in your array.

Comment: I just did. the thing is when I debug I get true on the right object.

Comment: What is the starting inventory?

Comment: You are asking for help in debugging your code. In order for me to do that, I need to reproduce your bug. In order for me to reproduce your bug, you need to [edit] your question and post a [mcve]. Are you willing to do that?

Comment: You have two apparent problems here (but you'd have to post what code prints that output and what data that is): 1. `inStock[i]--;` seems to have nothing to do with any particular book, even if you're doing it in the `if` block; and 2. You are running `return "book name" + book;` unconditionally, outside of the if block. You sure this is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try debugging your program.

- Put some print statements in the `equals` method to print the two books you are comparing to see if that is how you want to compare?  Print them at different locations in the logic and label them accordingly.
- Use some specially made `book` objects to test various `equals` conditions.
- And print the `instock` values after each decrement is made.

One of the best debugging tools around is the `print` statement.  Use it liberally.